# Getting real time coordinates of ImageView while it is in Translate Animation on android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an ImageView, set to Translate animation. I want real time coordinates of the ImageView when it is moving.

My code here:

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);

  Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(100, 200, 300, 400);
  animation.setDuration(1000);
  myimage.startAnimation(animation);
  animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

  int x = myimage.getLeft();
  int y = myimage.getTop();
```

Variables x and y don't updatee real time and only give original static coordinate of the ImageView.

How can I get the real time coordinates as the ImageView is in motion ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I didn't try after that, abandoned the project

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
   ImageView myimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);

  Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(100, 200, 300, 400);
  animation.setDuration(1000);
  myimage.startAnimation(animation);
  animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    int[] firstPosition = new int[2];
    myimage.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        myimage.getLocationOnScreen(firstPosition);
        int r = myimage.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[1];
        int rr = myimage.getMeasuredWidth() + firstPosition[0];
```

Comment: Still the same result. Coordinates don't update on Image Animation.

Comment: yes i did that. The values remain the same. Going through android developers for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] imageCordinates = new int[2];
                imgv1.getLocationOnScreen(imageCordinates);

                x = imageCordinates[0] + (imgv1.getWidth() / 2);
                y = imageCordinates[1] + (imgv1.getHeight() / 2);
```

Comment: Still the same result. Coordinates don't update on Image Animation.

Comment: setanimationlistener on it calculate x and y cordinate of imageview on animation end try this way...make two animation on first animation end calculate x and y then start second animation

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I got some pointers now. Studying it on android developers page. Will update if its done.