# How to detect if animated view touches another view?

Tags: android, animation, events, view

I have one view animated with transle animation:

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="110%p"
    android:duration="2000"
    />


public void translte(View v){
        Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.translate);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        v.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

And i want to detect if that view hits another view in its way.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28537655/4159909) related with animation positions and maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28763465/4159909) helps.