# How to get position of an animating view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a text view and I am setting moving animation on this view. Now I want to get each position in every mili second. Is this possible?? Or How can I check that this view is crossed a fix coordinate??

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537655/is-it-possible-to-get-real-time-coordinates-of-an-imageview-while-it-is-in-trans) would be a proper example for your case. You can see in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28763465/7483311) that you'll be able to get an animated view's position when it changes by using the `onAnimationUpdate` listener for an `ObjectAnimator` object,

I don't know if you are using the `ObjectAnimator` for your animation, and if you don't I suggest you doing so, because it would be an easy way to achieve what you want.