# How to get positon in TranslateAnimation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, animation

How to get Position of moving view using translate animation.

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 300.0f,
                    0.0f, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(500);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            mainview.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new AnimationListener, before the startAnimation command. You can use Override methods of AnimationListener and please debug it for a better understanding. You need setAnimationListener before starting your animation.